# If I have @fn then everything is being ignored

Tags: doxygen

Example:

```
/**
 * @fn IOChunk_t ioAllocateLargestChunk*(void)
 * @brief Allocates the largest available chunk.
 *
 * @return pointer to allocated @ref IOChunk_t or @ref NULL if allocation failed
 */
IOChunk_t* ioAllocateLargestChunk(void);    // Return the biggest normal chunk we can get (starting at 8k)
```

[image]

But if I remove `@fn` it works fine:

```
/**
 * @brief Allocates the largest available chunk.
 *
 * @return pointer to allocated @ref IOChunk_t or @ref NULL if allocation failed
 */
IOChunk_t* ioAllocateLargestChunk(void);    // Return the biggest normal chunk we can get (starting at 8k)
```

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What are your settings different from the default settings (i.e. result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`). What is the name of the file used (in this case is it a `.h` or `.cpp` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the function:

```
IOChunk_t* ioAllocateLargestChunk(void);
```

and in the comment you have:

```
@fn IOChunk_t ioAllocateLargestChunk*(void)
```

We see that these 2 definitions don't match (see position of the asterisks)

and your code should thus look like:

```
/**
 * @fn IOChunk_t* ioAllocateLargestChunk(void)
 * @brief Allocates the largest available chunk.
 *
 * @return pointer to allocated @ref IOChunk_t or @ref NULL if allocation failed
 */
IOChunk_t* ioAllocateLargestChunk(void);    // Return the biggest normal chunk we can get (starting at 8k)
```

Comment: It was autoamtically generated by the eclipse plugin. Bug

Comment: It is even better is to remove the redundant @fn statement altogether. It is not needed if the comment block is placed directly before the declaration.